# Auto-increment for alphabet using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying auto-increment using PHP to generate English alphabets instead numbers. I know how to do auto increment for numbers:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

But I want a way I can generate ABC instead 123.

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing a teacher would set as homework

Comment: I asked myself the same, for an efficient way without defining a separate array. I am an adult and it's no homework 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `chr` function together with ASCII code to generate them

For UpperCase:

```
for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++) {
    echo chr($i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For LowerCase:

```
for ($i = 97; $i <= 122; $i++) {
    echo chr($i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here the complete list of ASCII codes:
https://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 3):

Just get the ascii code for A and loop for 26

```
<?php
$a_is = ord('A');

for ( $ch=$a_is; $ch<$a_is+26; $ch++ ) {
    echo chr($ch) . PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Or set a char count

```
<?php
$a_is = ord('A');
$stop = 5;

for ( $ch=$a_is; $ch<$a_is+$stop; $ch++ ) {
    echo chr($ch) . PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare and increment strings the exact same way as numbers, just change the initialisation and exit conditions of the loop:

```
for($i='A'; $i<='C'; $i++) {
  echo $i, PHP_EOL;
}
```

> A
> B
> C

See https://eval.in/974692

Comment: Thanks but when I replace C with Z it is giving AA AB AC... instead loop end on Z

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `range` and use `foreach` to loop.

```
$letters = range("A","C");
foreach( $letters as $letter ) {
    echo $letter . "<br />";
}
```

This will result to:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an array of letters like so, and use the index of the forloop to loop through them.

```
$letters = array('a','b','c');

    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
    {
        echo  $letters[$i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, you could set a variable to $x = "abcdefg..." and echo substr($x, $i, 1). You will need to reset $i to 1 whenever it reaches 27.